# Populate date from database with a where statement to a matching row

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have  query that I run and it populates the spreedsheet and I want to run another query that will use the first selected values to bring the results back and append to the one I have on the sheet, I would like all the results to be populated as one range(column). So far my code only brings results to the selected cell which is where the column is supposed to be populated but as I loop through only that cell changes values opposed to what I want which is the next cell after the first in a row. Here is the code so far

```
 Dim rRange As Range

Dim rCell As Range
  Dim myArray As Variant


    Set rRange = Range("A5", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

myArray = rRange

    For Each rCell In rRange


        MsgBox rCell.value

        strSQL1 = "SELECT  MobileNumber as Number  FROM  assets where AllocatedTo = '" & rCell.value & "'"

     MsgBox strSQL1
     Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
rs1.Source = strSQL1
rs1.ActiveConnection = conn
rs1.Open

rs1.MoveFirst

Sheets("TestTim").Range("F5").CopyFromRecordset rs1

    Next rCell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to edit your question into English, to make sure I properly understood what you were asking. Try as I might, I failed. I am sorry, I am not completely sure what you are asking.

That said, I believe that you might want to `Sheets("TestTim").cells(rcell.row,6).CopyFromRecordset rs1` instead of put every record in the same cell.

I think that change may address what you are referring to when you say "only that cell changes values". I hope I am helpful. I understand what it is like to be required to work in a language where you are not a native speaker.

Comment: Thanks man for your help, but the suggestion you make does not write to the cells it shows the results exactly the way I want but only the last value of the loop is  written on the cell  one cell further from the last row.I need to be able to write these results back to each row that I loop through

Comment: I like to help, I hope I can. Let me make sure I understand. rRange has more than one cell in it (A5:A[some number greater than 5]), your msgbox's show the values for each of those cells in order, but column F is blank for each row.. until the first row outside of your range? As in, if your range were A5:A9, F5:F9 would be blank, but F10 would have a result?

Comment: I finally found the solution to my problem and this can be achieved by;     'Dim rRange As Range

Dim rCell As Range
 

Dim x As Integer
x = 5
    Set rRange = Range("A5", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))

 

    For Each rCell In rRange


        MsgBox rCell.value

        strSQL1 = "SELECT  MobileNumber as Number  FROM  assets where AllocatedTo = '" & rCell.value & "'"
 Range("H" & x).value =  strSQL1
    x = x + 1
     MsgBox strSQL1
     Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
rs1.Source = strSQL1
rs1.ActiveConnection = conn
rs1.Open

rs1.MoveFirst

    Next rCell'

Comment: Very glad you found a solution to your problem. However, the code you posted in comments (posting code in comments doesn't work well and rarely helps others trying to read it) doesn't actually do anything. Don't get me wrong, 'self-answering' this question with working code is a great idea, and I encourage you to post an answer here to help someone else, but all you do here is open the same recordset over and over, with a different query, never close it in between, and never do anything with the results. If all you wanted was to paste a string into col H, you probably don't need to open rs1.